# How to post radio button value false/0, if radio button option is not selected & set true/1, if value is selected in the form of array?

Tags: php

I need an array of radio type input field, array contain index value 0 if option is not selected & 1 if the option is selected.

This is form

[image]

This is HTML code

```
    <div class='input-group'>
        <input type="radio" name='correctOption[]'>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 
        {!! Form::text('optionText[]', '', array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'optionText1')) !!}
   </div>
```

I get array form value like this

[correctOption] => Array
        (
            [0] => on
        )

but I want like this

```
[correctOption] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0,
            [1] => 0,
            [2] => 1,
            [3] => 0,
            [4]=>0

        )
```

Comment: So change `value` attribute of your radio.

Comment: @Justinas, I add new attribute info like this <input type="radio" name="correctOption[]" info="1"> , now I am  not getting this array after submit form :(

Comment: You can't use any attribute name, it should be `value="1"` as Justinas said.

Comment: It literally must be `value` attribute, not some random `info` / `array-key` or anything.

Comment: Radio buttons are submitted by the name group they are bound to, thus only a single value for the radio button name group would be submitted.  Your current usage is saying `Question 1 = 1` regardless of the chosen answer. You should change the value of each radio button to the value it applies to: `value="Answer1"`, `value="Answer2"`, etc rather than all of them being equal to `1`. Then you would be able to update your input fields to reflect the value of the radio button. `name="Answer1" value="Test 1"` and you can match the missing `correctOption`  based on input names submitted.

Comment: I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557804/can-we-post-unchecked-radio-button-value

Comment: @AnkeshVaishnav, This is not working for me

Comment: @RajeevVarshney try something like https://jsfiddle.net/3vv3e13v/ Just use php instead of Javascript to process the form results.

Answer (score 0):

Because radio button will only ever give you a single value that the selected input has associated with, you should probably change `name` attribute of the `input` to something else than array.

```
<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="1">
```

Make sure that it does have a value so you can identify it by its value - otherwise you will not have a way of knowing which one was checked as all you will get is `correctOption=on` - so each input should have a different value i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="3">
```

As I can see, each radio button has a corresponding text input. Each of these inputs should probably have the id of the corresponding radio button as a key of the array they are bound to:

```
<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="1">
{!! Form::text('optionText[1]', '', array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'optionText1')) !!}

<input type="radio" name="correctOption" value="2">
{!! Form::text('optionText[2]', '', array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'optionText2')) !!}
```

What you could then do is to process the request by obtaining selected radio value and all text inputs - your request data will look something similar to:

```
[
    'correctOption' => 1,
    'optionText' => [
        1 => 'Content of text input 1',
        2 => 'Content of text input 2',
        3 => 'Content of text input 3',
    ]
]
```

With this request you know which option was selected and what other text inputs contain.
Because each text input has associated radio button, you could loop through the list of `optionText` and generate your `correctOptions` array - I would use `illuminate/support` package and its `Collection`, which makes this task really easy - something along the lines:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$requestData = $_POST;

$correctOption = $requestData['correctOption'];

$collection = new Collection($requestData['optionText']);

$correctOptions = $collection->map(function($value, int $index) use ($correctOption) {

    if ($index === $correctOption) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

})->toArray();
```